# Django + postgres relation does not exist error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I understand how many questions there are for this matter but none of the solutions suggested helped. 
I got the following problem: 
I deleted my models and deleted the imports in `admin.py` as well. Then I wanted to update the django database with `makemigrations` which shows that it deletes the model employee but then after using `migrate` command I saw an error that the relation does not exist. I also dropped it from the postgres database that I used. 
The strange thing here is that migrate keeps looking for the model which does not exists. Even if I create another one `makemigrations` detects it and then `migrate` says `relation project_employee..` 
Tried `syncdb --all` no success. here is the output of `migrate`

```
Apply all migrations: sessions, project, admin, auth, contenttypes
Running migrations:
Applying project.0003_auto_20160318_1215...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "project_employee" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field_by_name(self.name)[0])
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 431, in remove_field
self.execute(sql)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 111, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "project_employee" does not exist
```

`

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What helped finally was deleting the whole migrations folder from the project's folder. Saw some south responses as well, but haven't tried.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, you should not directly delete a table from the DB before the migration. If you change your model, then `manage.py migrate` will do the thing.

django cannot detect the direct change of DB; only knows the change of model script. Therefore if you drop a table, then django does not detect the change, so django keeps looking for the table which was dropped and gives the error.

Sometimes migration does not work for no reasons. in that case, I do the following things:

1. undo the change of models.py
2. do the django migration ( `manage.py makemigrations appname` works better than `manage.py makemigrations` )
3. if the migration works, then change the models.py again
4. do the django migration again

this works sometimes.

Comment: Well, I've never dropped a table without deleting the model first. The only tables I've deleted were the ones which models were deleted.. anyway deleting the whole migration folder solved it. Some suggest --fake ing it but it didn't help. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I tried this and it did not solve my issue. I also tried squashing and faking and nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this issue by the following steps

1. when I was running this command

   `python manage.py migrate app_name zero`

   it was complaining about that some table is missing. so I've created a dummy table with a dummy column.
2. I've run the command again

   `python manage.py migrate app_name zero`
3. I've applied the migrations for that app

   `python manage.py migrate app_name`

Answer (score 4):

Drop the tables in the db using the below code

```
python manage.py migrate app_name zero
```

Then again migrate

```
python manage.py migrate app_name
```

The reason is that there is already a table present, and when you do a "initial migration",Django will see that the initial migration has already been applied since the table is already present with old schema and therefore not taking the new table with different schema into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

All I needed to do was to create a table with the same name and one dummy column.  Then when I migrated, django remade all of the columns for me.

Answer (score 1):

What I did for me was to fake migration using the command below

```
python3 manage.py migrate yourapp --fake
```

Answer (score 0):

A necro by me, but if you dropped a table on a project with existing data and active migrations (Django, Postgres), your best bet is to drop the entire database (of course proceed with caution), recreate it, and then run manage.py migrate to re-initialize your environment.

It's the fastest way to soft reset and get in sync with the current build.

Answer (score -2):

Finally, it worked for me. I have to delete my all tables and then deleted migrations files.

Then tried the below *commands* manually :

```
python manage.py makemigrations [appname]

python manage.py migrate [appname]
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693150/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Answer (score -3):

finally this worked for me:

```
python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]

python manage.py migrate [app_name]
```

Comment: This is just generic migration code with no attempt to address the question.